# Edit form prop values not filled in the form vuejs (reusing same form component )

Tags: forms, vue.js, edit

I have a vuejs project, where I have my parent component as ProductGroup.vue which has a child ProductGroupmodal.vue. The productGroup has list of records, upon clicking edit button on each row the modal (ProductGroupmodal.vue) should pop up with the input fields filled with the data. I have passed each row data as prop to the child component on clicking edit button. Then, I have assigned the prop data to the form object in the created() method of child component. But the form is not filled with previous records.  Here is my code below:
This is Parent component.

```
<template>
  <div class="tables-basic">
    <h2 class="page-title">Product Group - <span class="fw-semi-bold">List</span></h2>
    <b-button v-b-modal.modal1 @click.prevent="newModal()">Add New</b-button>
    
    <b-row>
      <b-col>
          <div class="table-resposive">
            <table class="table">
              <thead>
                <tr>
                  <th>Name</th>
                  <th class="hidden-sm-down">Action</th>
                </tr>
              </thead>
              <tbody>

                <tr v-for="row in allData" :key="row.id">
                  <td>{{row.name}}</td>
                  <td>
                      <b-button v-b-modal.modal1 @click.prevent="editModal(row)">Edit</b-button>
                  </td>
                </tr>
              </tbody>
            </table>
          </div>
      </b-col>
    </b-row>

    <ProductGroupModal :editValue="editValue" :editing='editing'
    />
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import ProductGroupModal from '@/components/ProductGroup/ProductGroupModal.vue';

export default {
  name: 'ProductGroup',
  components: { ProductGroupModal },
  data() {
    return {
        editValue:{},
        editing: false,
        allData:{},
    };
  },
  methods: {
    loadData() {
      ProductGroupDataService.getAll()
        .then(response => {
          this.allData = response.data;
        })
        .catch(e => {
          console.log(e);
        });
    },
    newModal(){
        this.editing=false;
    },
    
    editModal(row){
        this.editValue = row;
        this.editing = true;
    },
  },
    mounted() {
        this.loadData();       
    }
};
</script>
```

This is my Child component (ProductGroupModal.vue):

```
<template>
    <b-modal ref="productGroupModal" id="modal1" centered v-bind:title="this.editing==true ? 'Update' : 'Add' "
      @hidden="resetModal"
      @ok.prevent="submitForm() ">
        <v-form ref="productGroupForm" id="productGroupForm">
            <v-text-field
            v-model="form.name"
            label="Name"
            required
            ></v-text-field>
        </v-form>
    </b-modal>
</template>

<script>
  import ProductGroupDataService from "@/services/ProductGroupDataService";

  export default {
        
        props: { 
            editValue: {
               type: Object,
               default: () => ({empty: true}),
           },
           editing: {
               type: Boolean,
                default: () => ({}),
           }
        },
        name: 'productGroupModal',
        data() {
            return {
                form: {
                    id: '',
                    name: '',
                    code: '',
                },
            };
        },
        methods:{
            submitForm() {
                var data = {
                    "name": this.form.name,
                    "code": this.form.code
                };
        },
        created(){
            if (!this.editValue.empty) {
                this.form = this.editValue
                console.log('edit:'+ this.editValue);
            }
            else{
                console.log('falseedit:'+ this.editValue);
            }
        }
  }
</script>
```

I think my b-modal(child component) is rendered before the data in the form is being set through prop .How can I solve it?Can anyone help me with this please!

Comment: Does adding the missing } in your child component fix your issue?

Comment: } isn't missing,perhaps when I discarded the unrelated codes, it got missed

Comment: Your child component code posted as done here misses one. Beside that this is far from a [mre] - it uses things not present. You might want to fix that and propose static data to your components so we can run this.

Answer (score 0):

I can't get enough info about your b-modal components.
but I think this maybe related to the props passed to child is async.
when created, the asyncprops editValue is not ready yet. so nothing is assigned to the form.
you can add v-if on the child component, render the child component only when data is ready:

```
<ProductGroupModal v-if="allData.length" :editValue="editValue" :editing='editing'
    />
```

do not write this.form = this.editValue in created hook;

```
computed: {
   form() {
      return this.editValue || {};
   }
}
```

Comment: After you pointed out about async, I think my b-modal is redered  before the form data is being set How can I solve it?

Comment: have you tryed the `v-if="allData.length"` I mentioned above?

Comment: what do you mean by not work? no modal shown or no data filled into the modal?

Comment: Sorry, but no data is filled

Comment: do not write `this.form = this.editValue` in created hook; try getter or computed;  
 if still not work, please show me the console.log(this. editValue)